# How to implement systems in ECS pattern/is my implementation reasonable?

Tags: c++, static, entity-component-system

I'm currently working on a simple game/game engine in C++ that uses an Entity Component System design pattern (wanted to learn how they worked), where each entity is just an ID to link to it's components, and the components are just POD structs. I have a Scene class which is essentially the current world that all entities (and components) belong to. My systems (Physics, Scripting, Collisions, Rendering, etc.) are currently implemented as their own classes which perform operations on sets of components in an update() function.

Each system is then held as a static member of the scene class like so:

```
class Scene
{
public:
    //Systems
    static PhysicsEngine sysPhysics;
    static CollisionSystem sysCollisions;
    static RenderSystem sysRender;
    static ScriptEngine sysScripting;
```

One of the issues of using static is there is no control over the lifetime of the systems, so the systems don't use constructors and destructors, and instead use an explicit init() and clean() function to initialise and destroy anything that needs to be initialised or destroyed, which are called in the Scene's init() and clean() functions.

However, I see a lot of criticism online over the use of static as bad practice, so I'm wondering if this is really a good way to implement my systems. I want to ensure that more than one of the same system per scene is not created. What would the alternatives be? I considered using an std::unique_ptr for each system, would this work?

Comment: What about having the systems as non-static members? You can't end up with multiple `PhysicsEngine` unless you either manually create one, or create a second `Scene`.

Comment: That would make sense, provided I'm careful about how I create my systems and scene's, is using static is sort of redundant here?